Nested Serializer with Foreign Key and to_field
Stock model has a OneToMany relationship with Data model. I am using the to_field to link them via model_number field.
class Stock(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    msrp = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.brand} - {self.model} - {self.model_number}"


class Data(models.Model):
    model_number = models.ForeignKey(Stock, to_field='model_number', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_number

I have my serializers to show each model number and then the nested relationship of data.
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'


class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = DataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['brand', 'model', 'model_number', 'msrp', 'data']

However the data does not return at all in my API view. Not sure where I am going wrong on this.

I made it possible to import the data associated with the foreign key of the stock model through methodfield.
stock/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Data, Stock

class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'


class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # data = DataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_data(self, obj):
      datas = Data.objects.filter(model_number=obj.model_number)
      serializer = DataSerializer(datas, many=True)
      return serializer.data
    

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = '__all__'

stock/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from .models import Stock
from .serializers import StockSerializer

# Create your views here.


class StockView(ListAPIView):
  queryset = Stock.objects.all()
  serializer_class = StockSerializer
  authentication_classes = []

drf document serializermethodfield


I actually ended up solving this by changing the ForeignKey on my Data model. The error also seemed to be resulting from my postgres not migrating properly at the time.
class Data(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name='data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_number

